# Consulta registro completo de una tabla y mostrar lo seleccionado de otra

Tags: sql

Tengo tabla tipospagos

```
Idpago | pago
----------------
  1    | efectivo
  2    | punto de venta
  3    | pago móvil
  4    | transferencia
  5    | divisa
  6    | otro
```

Tengo otra tabla misformaspago

```
Idformapago | idpago | idaliado
-------------------------------
    1       |   2    |    1
    2       |   3    |    1 
    3       |   4    |    1
    4       |   1    |    2
    5       |   2    |    2
```

Ahora necesito un query de consulta que me genere esto.

```
Idpago | pago.          | Idaliado |
-------------------------------------
  1    | efectivo       |  null    | 
  2    | punto de venta |    1     |  
  3    | pago móvil     |    1     |  
  4    | transferencia  |    1     |  
  5    | divisa         |   null   |
  6    | otro           |   null   |
```

Ojo quiero que salga todos los tipos de pagos y en otra columna los seleccionados por el IDaliado

Este el el query que estoy usando pero cuando le pongo la condición solo me trae los pagos seleccionados por el IDaliado y quiero que salgan todos los pago así no lo allá seleccionado el IDaliado

```
select a.idpago, b.pago
, case when b.idpago is null then 0 else 1 end as pos 
from tipospagos a 
left join misformaspago b on a.idpago = b.idpago 
where b.idaliado = 1
```

Ese query me muestra esto y no me sirve

```
idpago | pago            | pos
--------------------------------
   2   | punto de venta  | 1
   3   | pago móvil      | 1
   4   | transferencia   | 1
```

Esto me sirve aparte de esa consulta quiero que me aparezcan los otros pagos
Espero y me entiendan pero esto se me ha complicado

Answer (score 0):

La consulta que realizas devuelve lo que le pides, si quieres que te aparezcan los que no tienen asignado ningún `idaliado`, deberás incluir esa condición, en este caso le puedes añadir la condición que te muestre los que son `null`:

```
select a.idpago, b.pago
, case when b.idpago is null then 0 else 1 end as pos 
from tipospagos a 
left join misformaspago b on a.idpago = b.idpago 
where b.idaliado = 1 OR b.idaliado is null
```

Comment: Ya lo he intentado con esa condiciona y me muestra es esto: 
 idpago | pago            | pos
--------------------------------
   2   | punto de venta  | 1
   3   | pago móvil        | 1
   4   | transferencia     | 1 
   1   | efectivo             | 0
   6   | otros                | 0
Pero no me muestras  
   5  | divisa                | 0